# SQL there was a problem sending the command to the program

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I'm using Windows 7 and SQL Server 2008 R2 and whenever I try and double click a .sql file I get some stupid error "there was a problem sending the command to the program" does anyone know how to fix this? I have UAC keep popping up whenever I open SQL server or BIDS, but seems fine with Vis studio 2010 for some reason... oh and I checked that the exe was running as admin, I saw that posted somewhere...

Comment: are .sql files correctly associated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mine does the same at first.

Run regedit and go to the following key:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sqlwb.sql.9.0\Shell\Open\Command

Edit the default value to add "%1" to the end.

The value should now look like the following:

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe" /dde "%1"

(note double quotes around the %1)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Please read "David Derman" answer below as well. In my case Andrew's + David's solution solved the problem. I had to do both.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue and changing the REG key didn't work.  Turned out setting the program to always run as an administrator was the problem.  You have to go into the SSMS.exe properties, go to the compatability tab, and uncheck the "Run this program as an administrator" checkbox.

Comment: This is the TRUE answer.

Answer (score 5):

The key "sqlwb.sql.9.0" was replaced to "ssms.sql.11.0" in new version MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic but I want to share my experience.

I had the same problem running Visual Studio 2013 (VS2013) on Windows 8.1.

I believe I caused the problem trying to solve the problem with UAC administration permissions to run the VS. First I went to the installation folder, right click over the devenv.exe file, Compatibility option. At the first time I'd chosen the Permisions solution and it probably gave me a another problem, no files was opening in VS and the error message "There was a problem sending the command to the program". After long days suffering with this issue I tried today back to the Compatibility option and then I tried the "Recommended Settings" option.
Problem solved!

It wasn't necessary to change anything in the regedit.