# Error opening the .sql file

Tags: sql-server-2008

Whenever I double click on .sql file. I receive a message that 'There was a problem sending the command to the program'

Answer (score 1):

See the [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f8d65de5-11b5-4792-bb03-b7690f53bb31/sql-file-will-not-open-in-ssms-on-doubleclick-or-jump-list?forum=sqltools) which says:

> Ah... I think the solution is to make the string for
>
> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sqlwb.sql.9.0\Shell\Open\Command
> ```
>
> say this:
>
> ```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe" "%1" /dde
> ```
>
> with quotes around the %1.  It works for me now.
>
> I think this is a bug in SQL Server 2008 client tools.

Comment: I tried .after IDE ....ì having some dll files.....not seen any exe files on there.....wat can  i do?

Comment: @s.keerthividhyasagar:- Did you check the answer of David [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526982/sql-there-was-a-problem-sending-the-command-to-the-program)

Comment: @s.keerthividhyasagar:- You need to Run regedit and then find the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. I don't know what problem it, but I have fixed it with a registry hack.

1. Run regedit and go to the following key:
2. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sqlwb.sql.9.0\Shell\Open\Command
3. Update the (Default) value
4. It should contain something like: "c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SQL
   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe" /dde
5. add "%1" to the end
6. the value sholud now like this: "c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft SQL
   Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe" /dde "%1"